# Working with Calendar in Data list in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, database, calendar, datalist

I am using datalist to display data from the database,I have got three fields whose Data Type is datetime, What I was looking for is to display a calendar in the datalist , with date selected(coming from database), Also the user can use that calendar to change date , which should update the date field in the database when update is clicked,

Is there any way to integrate calendar in the datalist as perform the above requirements.

Any assistance or suggestions will be appreciated

Comment: I'm not sure what you meant by "datalist". Take a look at jquery-ui datepicker. It can be attached to a visible/hidden textbox, and it renders a nice calendar. Either way, you're looking into some javascript coding to trigger the postback or otherwise pass selected date/time to the server.

Comment: Datalist control is built in asp.net

Comment: well i can use that for displaying , but what about updating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not specifically promoting Jquery-UI, as there are many js-driven calendars out there, but I've been using it in many different scenarios, and I'm sure it can work in whatever scenario you can imagine: http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

That control has events, in particular onClose and onSelect. When those happen, you have your date. You can send it to the server either via AJAX or via form-submit (postback).

Also, ASP.NET has a built-in calendar control that supports postbacks, if that's what you are looking for.

Comment: hi i tried using jquery calender using $('#<%=txtCallBackDate.ClientID %>').datepicker(); but its not picking up the txtCallBackDate as the textbox is in the datalist

Comment: i cant get the client id of the bounded field in datalist

Comment: set the value of the textbox to that date, in the same format as the datepicker assumes it to be; e.g. txtCallBackDate.Text = "01/27/2012"; otherwise, the datepicker defaults to current date; take a look at other options of datepicker (at that url).

Comment: you should be able to still find those textboxes. maybe you can set CssClass property to something that you can use query to identify. e.g $("input.datebox").datepicker()